# Horizontal scroll of images overflow issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I have this one file where I want to create a horizontal scroller to move one image at a time to the left or the right. 
The problem with it is that the set of images is moving to the left or right but ending up over the previous or the next button
[image: This is how it starts]

[image: Clicking on "next" button]

The html and css code is in the jsfiddle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a.abc").click(function() {
    $('.cmioProductThumbnail').animate({"left":"-=100px"},800)
});
$("a.def").click(function() {
    $(".cmioProductThumbnail").each(function(){
        $(this).animate({"left":"+=100px"},800)

    });

});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/ZkXvX/

How do I solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: demo has nothing to do with problem shown

Answer (score 0):

While the jsfiddle is totally unrelated to the code in your question, I'm sure you can fix your problem by wrapping a fixed sized `div` with `overflow: hidden;` around the `div` containing your images.